# Quantity selector in prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Is there a form (or default) in prestashop, to show the quantities in a select box and that the price will change according to my choice?

Otherwise, can the selector (+ or -) move forward or backward for a certain amount?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: on the cart page, the cart quantity field change the price when you click on + or -

Answer (score 1):

You will find the functions in cart-summary.js

```js
 $('.cart_quantity_up').off('click').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  upQuantity($(this).attr('id').replace('cart_quantity_up_', ''));
  $('#' + $(this).attr('id').replace('_up_', '_down_')).removeClass('disabled');
 });
 $('.cart_quantity_down').off('click').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  downQuantity($(this).attr('id').replace('cart_quantity_down_', ''));
 });
 $('.cart_quantity_delete' ).off('click').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  deleteProductFromSummary($(this).attr('id'));
```